# CanvasJS - label bubbles in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, canvasjs

I am trying to find a way to label each and every bubble in the CanvasJS bubble chart. Is there any way to label each bubble or provide name to each bubble?

Answer (score 4):

Monsta,

Are you looking for [indexLabel](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/)?

[image]